# Accidentally unregistered sandbox account

Tags: yodlee

I accidentally executed the `unregister` API call on one of the five default sandbox accounts (username: sbMemXXX2, password: sbMemXXX2#123) when I was playing around with Test Drive. Attempting to log into it in Test Drive will return `{"error":["Invalid User Credentials"]}`. My other four sandbox accounts still work properly.

According to the docs, the `register3` API functionality is disabled for the sandbox endpoint so I'm not sure how I can recover or remake this sandbox account. Does anyone know how to do this or do I need to contact Yodlee support?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you are right, you won't be able to register a user in developer sandbox environment.
We recommend you to use the remaining 4 pre-provisioned user for testing purpose.

Hope this helps

Regards,

Krithik

Comment: So there's no way to get this sandbox account back?